# Loose Coupling Presenter to View in MVP

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, architecture, mvp

We work in a Java shop here and our web application uses an implementation of the [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) architectural pattern. Our manager comes from a .NET world, where he has been exposed to the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) design pattern. Our manager is advocating changes in our MVP implementation, including that the Presenters should be decoupled from (or loosely coupled to, depending on your interpretation) its Views via the Observer design pattern, in tradition with MVVM. I am more of the opinion that the Presenter and the View work together to achieve a common goal, and as such should be coupled.

Among the arguments brought up in support of the change is the ability to unit test Presenters. If the Presenters only see the views as Observers, the argument goes, then they can be more easily unit tested. But presenters strongly coupled to their views are not necessarily difficult to test. If the View uses the [Humble View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) paradigm, then it can be mocked. And finally, testability should be a symptom of good design, not a driver for the design.

Another argument used by my manager in support of layering the Views and the Presenters is the supposed maturity of MVVM. As such, we should follow MVVM's teachings and adapt to its implementation of MVP. Correct me if I'm wrong, but MVVM imposes the (artificial) layering of views and presenters in order to facilitate its data bindings in controls.

Can you please help us see the light here? Why should we use a decoupled model and pay the price for it? I'm not seeing the benefit. Occam's razor says I need arguments to use decoupling, and testing doesn't seem to be one of them.

---

**Clarification**: What I'm really looking for with this question are the arguments that can tip the balance in favor of a presenter that doesn't know about its view and shoots events in the aether or in favor of a presenter that knows about its view(s) through more direct coupling, like a humble view interface or directly to the class. Note that presenters can easily serve multiple views with both loose and tight coupling. The difference is in the interface that the presenter talks to: with loose coupling, the presenter talks to listener classes (or an event bus representative), whereas with tight coupling, the presenter talks to the view interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Looks like the TS does not asking whether to pass `interface` instead of `class` to the `presenter`, but whether the `presenter` are communicating to the `view` via another layer (let's call observable). It is simply try to reflect `MVVM` pattern used in `WPF` for the view management. If that's the case then all of my arguments before are invalid.

Personally, I think that the approach is bad and does not give many benefits instead of cons. Here is the points I would like to mention:

1. `Humble view` is already enough for maintainability

   As stated by the TS, humble view already sufficient for creating testable classes and modular enough for separation of concern / responsibility. You can see the revision of my answer stated that humble view is already maintainable.
2. It added complexity and learning curve

   Unless your approach are supported by built-in distributed library such as WPF, then you are in doom for learning the approach. It is not common and new developers will find it hard to learn your design.
3. It reduces code discoverability

   My experience with WPF is that without proper agreement in folder structure you will find it hard to discover the presenter (because it will refer to observable). WPF have some guidelines with folder structure (called conventions) so new developers which understand WPF will understand it.
4. Harder to debug

   If the binding (listening point) is declared mistakenly, you will get a hard time finding the mistake. Most of the times the mistake gives you wrong exception. Even in WPF, newcomers will find hard to debug.
5. Harder to ensure property update and more risk for infinite cycle

   During developing WPF I find it hard to ensure property update between the view and presenter (viewmodel). `MVVM` design which listen to changes such as Knockout and WPF have higher risk of infinite cycle occuring (change in prop A updates prop B which updates prop A and so on).
6. You baypassed the compiler validation

   What I don't like with `WPF` / `MVVM` is that the compiler cannot help validate your binding. It means that `null reference` and `data type error` can only be handled in runtime level.
7. It is not implementable to web apps.

   The observable layer may be useful in event-driven apps such as desktop app or even mobile app. However in web apps which structure based on `Request -> Response` it is just a useless layer of abstraction. I have yet found any presenter logic which can be used in both web and apps architecture. If it will be duplicated anyway, why not make it more simpler? Moreover `Humble View` approach may be used (not perfectly, but can) in web architecture.
8. You will need BLL anyway

   No matter what architecture you build, you still only handle the code in `PL` level only. You will still need `BLL` in another layer to ensure the business logic can be reused no matter what the UI is (web / desktop).
9. The benefit is just another layer of separation

   I don't know what you want to approach in java. However in WPF I find it is easier and safer (in terms of not breaking the viewmodel / presenter) to modify the view.

**Summary:**

With `MVP` using `observable`, you violate `KISS` / `YAGNI`. If you does not use distributed library, you also violate `Reinvent the Wheel`. The only benefit is to support for `DRY` (to manage data binding) but since it cannot be used in web structure, the benefit is not worth it.

Comment: OK, but if the presenter is loosely coupled using the Observer pattern, there is no need for the view to have an interface (unless you're talking about the listener interface that the view will implement, which is not what I'm talking about). If the Presenter is instead coupled to the view through its interface, I would still argue it's tightly coupled to the view, as long as it directly calls methods on that interface. At least in that sense, you seem to be agreeing with me and disagreeing with my manager. Am I right?

Comment: As far as a presenter having multiple views, it's possible with both loose and tight coupling. With loose coupling of the observer kind, the presenter holds a collection of observers that it will later notify. With tight coupling to the view or to its distilled interface, the presenter holds a collection of view objects. A collection will be used in both cases, then, in order to create a one-to-many mapping from presenter to views.

Comment: To answer your points one by one: (1) easy to address with humble view. (2) humble view does the same. (3) humble view achieves this. (4) I don't think this is an argument for loose coupling. This can be done just as well with tight coupling. It's a simple matter of how much responsibility we want to give to the view. (5) not an argument for loose coupling. Tight coupling achieves this just as well.

Comment: @MihaiDanila Looks like I missed some points in your explanation. Would you please explain more about the design current / to be? In my current understanding is you are passing your concrete view class to the presenter instead of using interface.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about an interface in the question (namely, the "humble view"). I'm asking why the presenter should prefer not to call into a view interface and rather it should prefer to dispatch events that the view must first register for. I'm looking for an argument either way, a better one than "MVVM is doing it this way"). Why would we pay the price for the loose coupling? Testability, and your other points, are all touchable with a humble view, and the bonus is that the coupling is exposed in an interface, not smeared throughout the implementation. So, why loose coupling?

Comment: I don't want to confuse you, so take this as a footnote to my previous clarification. In practice, of course, we won't go crazy with view interfaces until it becomes necessary to do so. If the presenter requires testing, and the view can't be tested (btw, we use Vaadin, so most of our views can probably be unit tested), then you can extract an interface. Of course even if you don't have a true interface in the mix, the view class still has an *interface* (i.e., public methods), which we still keep humble (i.e. abstract, high level), and which we can readily turn into a Java interface.

Comment: Please clarify one thing: Currently you already have the presenter talks directly to interface (which implemented in view), then your manager asked to use observable instead of view interface for so?

Comment: Correct, views register as listeners to presenters, which dispatch events using Observables. (In addition, as per MVVM, views don't talk to models directly, and all of the above imply a layering situation: model -> presenter -> view) with each layer not knowing about the ones above it. Layering is nice, but definitely not something I would force onto my design. Why shouldn't view and presenter know about each other? :)

Answer (score 2):

You and/or your manager may be confusing dependency *direction* and coupling *tightness*.

The essential difference between MVVM and (Passive View) MVP is that in the former, thanks to bindings and commands, the ViewModel basically has no knowledge of the View. The dependency goes from View to ViewModel. In Passive View MVP, it goes the other way - the Presenter points to the View, populating its data and listening to its events.

It does not need to be a tight coupling though - you can couple the Presenter to an *abstraction* of a View which can be embodied by a mock in a test context. This is loose coupling.

That being said, I agree with you that both patterns (MVVM and Passive/Humble View) are roughly equally testable. Plus, MVVM is essentially valid in a .Net environment where you can leverage bindings and commands, which makes that specific pattern a strange call in a Java ecosystem. Similar approaches may exist in the Java world, but they aren't called MVVM.

Comment: I thought coupling is directly impacted by changing the direction of component dependencies, making the two go hand in hand in effect. If a presenter depends on a view interface (whether `interface` or public class API) being there, then is it not tightly coupled to its view? But assuming you are correct in making the distinction you're making, can one not also say that a presenter that talks to a view abstraction is tightly coupled to that abstraction, whereas one that dispatches events to listeners is loosely coupled to the views that will register as observers of those event?

Comment: I'd say an object that dispatches events is not coupled at all to its listeners. It has no notion of their existence. There could be hundreds of different listeners, or no one listening for all it cares. Being coupled to something means you rely on it to run, and changes in that thing may affect you, which is usually bad in terms of maintainability. Loose coupling via abstractions removes the adherence to implementation details, leaving only reliance on a contract. Then you could say we're tightly coupled to a contract, but it's one of the least intrusive forms of coupling.

Comment: OK, I can see coupling and dependencies in this light, but I still can't digest your argument that "there could be hundreds of listeners or none for all it cares." But doesn't the same apply for a presenter tightly coupled to its views? It could hold a collection of zero views or one of many views, for all it cares.

Comment: I feel coupling must be interpreted at a more abstract level than whether we see the other component through an interface or an implementation class: the more the changes to the component impact you, the more coupled you are to it. At one extreme, you may be coupled to low level details which change often. But this could be true with an interface or without one. At the other, you are coupled very indirectly. Not needing feedback from the component (like with most embodiments of Observer) gives you extra looseness. Abstraction is orthogonal to interface, and it means taking out the details.

Comment: You can do this with or without an interface. Going back to coupling, I'd say that the Observer pattern promotes one of the loosest forms of coupling. Some texts on Observer agree, stating "Observer promotes loose coupling". Also, definitions for de-/loose/tight coupling such as the ones on Webopedia suggest that there are shades of gray between these concepts (http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/T/tight_coupling.html).

Comment: *"But doesn't the same apply for a presenter tightly coupled to its views? It could hold a collection of zero views or one of many views, for all it cares"* In my experience, a Presenter will typically have only one View. If the View is not there at runtime, it will result in a null exception.

Comment: I agree that there are more ways of achieving loose coupling than just abstractions/interfaces. However, I believe it's the one that matters in your specific example. I don't think the direction of dependency determines coupling tightness (and thus maintainability) here - between a View that depends on a ViewModel and a Presenter that depends on a View, can you really tell which relationship is more loosely coupled ?

Comment: It matters to the presenter testing effort. If your presenter depends on the view, then you more or less have to offer mock support for the view and therefore hide the implementation class behind a Java `interface`. But if the view depends on the presenter with the presenter being decoupled thanks to, for example, *Observer*, then no view mocks are needed. Arguably you're more likely to unit test presenters than views. Leading us to my question: should presenter use loose coupling (via strong view abstraction), or decoupling (via *Observer*)? (tried using your terminology) Which would you use?

Comment: So this difference in testing effort could be used as an argument for decoupling via Observer, but of course testing is just as achievable without decoupling presenter from view. Is mine one of those questions where there isn't a clearcut answer? Should Occam's razor come to the rescue here, which in my mind would vote against the use of *Observer*?

Comment: Occam's razor indeed ;) Frankly, my impression is that your manager suffers from some kind of "new broom syndrome". Not having to mock the View isn't enough of a benefit to justify sweeping an entire presentation layer blank, especially considering that MVVM brings other problems (MVP tests using mocks guarantee that the Presenter pushes the right data into the View, while the MVVM equivalent doesn't guarantee the View listens to changes in the ViewModel correctly)

Comment: Unless, that is, the unit test includes listener registration, which makes that aspect just as testable with the Observer pattern. A bigger problem with decoupling via Observer is that it seems to allow the set of supported features in the view to slip, forcing the Presenter to provide a superset of what views might need. It seems that the realities of the actual views would still exert forces on the Presenter that would be akin to those exerted by a direct coupling. Anyway.

Comment: Interestingly, my manager's model would simplify certain cases. If the view needs to enter a mode that includes changing the enabled state of controls and changing the data in a table (perhaps we're changing the filtering mode), then in my model the view has to tell the presenter to update the data and to tell the view to change modes, or worse, it changes mode itself hoping the presenter will change the data. In his model, the view controls all of that, just asking the presenter for the data for the new mode.